# How to emit a delayed signal in PyQt GUI?

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt, signals-slots

In my PyQt GUI app, there are a lot of spinBoxes that trigger a lengthy setup routine when their values are changed.

My problem is this:
When typing in (large) numbers the `spinBox.valueChanged()` signal is emitted every time I input a single digit. That leads to the setup function being called many more times than necessary.

Is there a way to delay the trigger until I'm done typing the number and then fire the signal only once?
How do you usually take care of that issue in your GUIs?

I found [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Delay_action_to_wait_for_user_interaction) but I think it would involve creating an extra timer for every unique function I want to call upon emitting. That doesn't seem very elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For spinboxes there is the [keyboardTracking](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#keyboardTracking-prop) property.

If keyboard tracking is disabled, the spinbox doesn't emit the valueChanged() signal while typing. It emits the signal later, when the return key is pressed, when keyboard focus is lost, or when other spinbox functionality is used, e.g. pressing an arrow key.

I believe this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you! I'll combine your solution with Brendan's. That seems to give the 'laziest' behaviour for the spinBox.

Answer (score 3):

You can also connect to the [`editingFinished`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractspinbox.html#editingFinished) signal, which isn't emitted until the user presses enter or the spinbox loses focus.  However, you'll get this signal even if the value doesn't change, so you may want to check it against the last value to prevent having to run the lengthy routine unnecessarily.